# VirtualBox Critical Error - Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox

I have installed VirtualBox under Windows 8, so that I can use Windows XP in a virtual machine.

I have successfully installed VirtualBox, and I used the Windows XP image perfectly after the initial install, but now when I try to start VirtualBox, it shows this error:

```
Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object.
The application will now terminate.
Callee RC: CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005)
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm guessing you've probably either resolved this or given up by now ;) but just in case:

For me, in Windows 7, the resolution was to right click on the shortcut icon for Virtualbox and click **Run as administrator**. I imagine the Windows 8 solution is similar too / possibly permissions related.

Comment: Thank yochannah. I had the same issue. But when I run Virtual Box as Administrator Its working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Am running Windows 8. This fixed the problem for me. Thanks.

Comment: I had installed VM and I uninstalled and installed another version in windows 7.I run as administrator.I still got the error. any ideas?

Comment: I don't wanna run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a combination of using Windows 8 dexpot with virtualbox assigned to be moved to a secondary desktop on launch and when that second dexpot desktop had the taskbar (or maybe the just system tray) hidden.

Answer (score 0):

In my Windows 8.1, I had the Virtual Machine service for Hyper V running. I stopped it from Task manager and VirtualBox started OK. FYI : I was trying to use

```
vboxmanage setextradata "MAC OS X" "CustomVideoMode1" "1360x768x32"
```

to change my virtualised mac resolution when I got the above error while running VirtualBox in Admin mode.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps as below:

```
Navigate to your profile and look for the .VirtualBox folder. For example, C:\Users\your.name\.VirtualBox

Copy the VirtualBox.xml to somewhere safe, like your desktop

Uninstall VirtualBox

Delete the .VirtualBox folder

Re-install VirtualBox and the option package.

Start VirtualBox

Close VirtualBox

Navigate to your profile and look for the .VirtualBox folder. For example, C:\Users\your.name\.VirtualBox

Rename the VirtualBox.xml to VirtualBox.xml.old

Copy your original VirtualBox.xml to the .VirtualBox folder

Start VirtualBox
```

Answer (score 0):

if Still Nothing works Try this on windows 7 :

1. right click the virtual box icon --> TroubleShoot Compatibility
2. check the first option on checklist that says worked on earlier virsions
3. set it up as Windows XP service pack 2.
4. and Start .

It Will work :)